# Where can I pay artists to make models for my game?

Tags: models, art

Lets say I get some money for my hobby project, and I would like to start filling it up with good models, instead of some cheap placeholder ones. What are some sites where I can pay people to make models for the game? How much would it cost per asset?

**Edit:** I don't want to hire anybody. I just want to pay them for individual assets.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find artists to work on my game?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/775/how-do-i-find-artists-to-work-on-my-game)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As some one who ventured a bit into the creation of art, I would really advise you to get in touch with one rather than just "buying" models.

Art from different sources rarely work together (unless of course, they are meant to be) and high quality models alone won't make good graphics, everything needs to be put together with a sense of aesthetics to really convey a sense of quality. Just like starting writing a game without really having a idea how it should be structured doesn't really work just putting some graphics together won't really work either. It really requires expertise. Not just expertise in modelling/painting/pixeling but also in style and aesthetics.

So if you already know someone who is adept in digital art approach him, if not you might want to lurk somewhere (for example some IRC-Channel of some online community) with some artists.

If you have someone ask him about your game, ask what he thinks, ask how he would approach it from a art perspective. You might ask him whether he could do some graphics for it. Just make sure he is a part of the project, and not just some work slave.

Comment: I would give you +42 if I could for "Art from different sources rarely work together"

Answer (score 7):

You can always use [oDesk](https://www.odesk.com) or [eLance](https://www.elance.com). The former offers per-hour jobs, the latter offers fixed-price jobs. I've used them before, oDesk for art assets. You just need to be picky and not pay more than X hours a week; but it can backfire.

I recommend eLance, therefore.

Comment: If you were to add links I'd upvote...

Comment: Google is your friend ...

Comment: +1 for @Jimmy adding links and overcoming your obstinate refusal.

Comment: You guys are hilarious ... !!

Answer (score 4):

While I haven't officially used it yet, I was told that the DeviantArt marketplace is a great place to find artists eager for work:

http://forum.deviantart.com/jobs/offers/

Comment: And there are a lot of talented artists there. I have so many desktop images from that site.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to look on sites like [turbosquid](http://www.turbosquid.com/) and such ? They are full of quality assets, some of them game-ready.

You can get models for free, up to a few thousand dollars for the best ones (the ones I was looking was for an entire city).

EDIT: Looks like turbosquid now also does custom 3D models !

Answer (score 1):

Also check out Freelancer:
http://www.freelancer.com/jobs/Game-Design/

I haven't advertised there before specifically in the gaming section, but got work from it before for webdesign and it is a big site.

But anyway, I'd recommend just googling around for their communities/forums then hanging out there for a bit (if you get lucky you might find somebody who agrees to partner with you for free? If it is non-commercial?).