# Find a partner to build a game with

Tags: art

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find artists to work on my game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/775/how-do-i-find-artists-to-work-on-my-game)

I have started working on a spacesim game but my art is terrible...

Is there a website where I could find people who might be interested in collaborating on a game with me?

Comment: I'm actually developing a site for artists, programmers, writers, and musicians to exchange game assets and collaborate: http://gdcore.com. We got quite a few sign-ups, and we are currently in the process of opening it up.

Comment: @tyjkenn I just requested an invite to your site. It look cool.